# Oracle Natural Joins and Count(1)

Tags: oracle, natural-join

Does anyone know why in Oracle 11g when you do a Count(1) with more than one natural join it does a cartesian join and throws the count way off?

Such as

```
SELECT Count(1) FROM record NATURAL join address NATURAL join person WHERE status=1
AND code = 1 AND state = 'TN'
```

This pulls back like 3 million rows when

```
SELECT * FROM record NATURAL join address NATURAL join person WHERE status=1
AND code = 1 AND state = 'TN'
```

pulls back like 36000 rows, which is the correct amount.

Am I just missing something?

Here are the tables I'm using to get this result.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
address_id           NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
address_1            VARCHAR2(60)  NULL,
address_2            VARCHAR2(60)  NULL,
city                 VARCHAR2(35)  NULL,
state                CHAR(2)       NULL,
zip                  VARCHAR2(5)   NULL,
zip_4                VARCHAR2(4)   NULL,
county               VARCHAR2(35)  NULL,
phone                VARCHAR2(11)  NULL,
fax                  VARCHAR2(11)  NULL,
origin_network       NUMBER(3,0)   NOT NULL,
owner_network        NUMBER(3,0)   NOT NULL,
corrected_address_id NUMBER(10,0)  NULL,
"HASH"                 VARCHAR2(200) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rates (
rate_id      NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
eob          VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
network_code NUMBER(3,0)  NOT NULL,
product_code VARCHAR2(2)  NOT NULL,
rate_type    NUMBER(1,0)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE records (
pk_unique_id      NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
rate_id           NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
address_id        NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
effective_date    DATE         NOT NULL,
term_date         DATE         NULL,
last_update       DATE         NULL,
status            CHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
network_unique_id VARCHAR2(20) NULL,
rate_id_2         NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
contracted_by     VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
contract_version  VARCHAR2(5)  NULL,
bill_address_id   NUMBER(10,0) NULL
);
```

I should mention this wasn't a problem in Oracle 9i, but when we switched to 11g it became a problem.

Comment: Describe those tables. Do you get the same results if you explicitly specify the inner join?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My advice would be to NOT use NATURAL JOIN. Explicitly define your join conditions to avoid confusion and "hidden bugs". Here is the [official NATURAL JOIN Oracle documentation](http://68.142.116.68/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#sthref9907) and [more discussion](http://awads.net/wp/2006/03/20/back-to-basics-inner-joins/#comment-2837) about this subject.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  This helped me diagnose my bug (http://gist.github.com/72614) that turned out to be due to NATURAL JOINs.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens exactly as you say then it **must** be an optimiser bug, you should report it to Oracle.

Comment: [Bug 5031632 - Wrong results from NATURAL JOIN, Metalink Note: 5031632.8](https://community.oracle.com/thread/974712?tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

you should try a count(*)

There is a difference between the two.
count(1) signifies count rows where 1 is not null
count(*) signifies count the rows

Comment: Since 1 is never null, there is no difference in potential results.

Comment: ... and count(1) is rewritten to count(*) anyway. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed you used 2 natural joins...
From the documentation you can only use a natural join on 2 tables
[Natural_Join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Natural_join)

Comment: That is incorrect (and the site you referenced is not the documentation, it is an independent Wiki):

See http://68.142.116.68/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9834